# proof of non Turing-computable function g

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

In one of my lessons about turing machines I have been taught that the function g is not computable:
\begin{cases}g(n)=f_{n}(n)+1 & \text { if } f_{n}(n) \text { is defined } \\ g(n)=1 & \text { if } f_{n}(n) \text { is undefined }\end{cases}

Proof: 
If $g$ is computable, then it can be computed by some Turing machine. Assume it's encoding is $k$.
$$
\begin{cases}g(k)=f_{k}(k)+1 & \text { if } f_{k}(k) \text { is defined } \\ g(k)=1 & \text { if } f_{k}(k) \text { is undefined }\end{cases}
$$
but both are not equal to $f_{k}(k)$ so the function g can not be computable.  My teacher also made some sort of table and talked about diagonalization, but I couldn't follow the proof at all.
Could someone explain this proof to me in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Assign an integer to each Turing machine.

First, we fix an encoding scheme (or method) for all Turing machines (of some fixed kind, such as the one defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition)) that encodes each Turing machine into a string of 0s and 1s. This string is interpreted as a positive integer in binary form.

Hence each Turing machine corresponds to an integer.  Conversely, a positive integer may correspond to a Turing machine. For a positive integer $n$, if $n$ corresponds to a Turing machine, use $f_n$ to denote that Turing machine. Otherwise, $f_n$ is undefined.

##### Diagonalization

$$\text{For all }n\in\mathbb N,\ g(n)=\begin{cases}f_{n}(n)+1 & \text { if both } f_{n}\text{ and }f_n(n) \text { are defined,} \\ 1 & \text { otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

The statement above defines a function $g$ from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

##### Why is $g$ not computable?

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $g$ is computable.

Then $g$ can be computed by some Turing machine. Assume that Turing machine is encoded as positive integer $k$. That is, that Turing machine is $f_k$.

What is the value of $g$ at $k$? Since $g$ is computed by $f_k$, $g(k)=f_k(k)$.

On the other hand, replacing $n$ by $k$ in the definition of $g$, we have

$$g(k)=\begin{cases}f_{k}(k)+1 & \text { if both } f_{k}\text{ and }f_k(k) \text { are defined,} \\ 1 & \text { otherwise}\end{cases}$$
There are two possible cases.

- Both $f_{k}$ and $f_k(k)$ are defined.
  Then $g(k)=f_k(k)+1$, which is not equal to $f_k(k)$.
- Otherwise, $f_k(k)$ is undefined (that is, the Turing machine that computes $g$ does not halt when the input is $k$).
  Then $g(k)=1$, which is not equal to $f_k(k)$ since $f_k(k)$ is undefined.

So in all cases, $g(k)\not=f_k(k)$, which contradicts the fact that $g(k)=f_k(k)$. This contradiction shows our assumption, $g$ is computable must be wrong.

##### Where does the trick come from?

We want to construct/describe/define a function $g$ that is not computed by any Turing machine.

More explicitly, for each Turing machine, we want to do two things:

- find a number
- describe the value of $g$ at that number so that the value is different from the output of that Turing machine given that number as input.

A simple approach is to use the same number always, say $2022$ or $152866$. However, whatever value we let $g(2022)$ or $g(152866)$ be, there is a Turing machine that outputs $g(2022)$ given $2022$ as input (and outputs $g(152866)$ given $152866$ as input).

The idea is to find a different number for each different Turing machine.

For a Turing machine and the corresponding number, we will let $g$ at that number be any value that is different from the output of that Turing machine. For example, $g(k)=f(k) + 153595$. For example, $g(k)=f(k)^2 + 42$. If $f$ does not halt on $k$, $g(k)=91753$. The viable options are endless.

(Of course, we can also choose $g(k)=f(k)+1$ if $f$ halts on $k$ and $g(k)=1$ if $f$ does not halt on $k$.)

How can we find a different number for each different Turing machine? The encoding number of a Turing machine!

##### Exercises

Exercises 1. Function $h$ defined below is not computable.
$$\text{For all }n\in\mathbb N,\ h(n)=\begin{cases}2^{f_n(n)} & \text { if both } f_{n}\text{ and }f_n(n) \text { are defined,} \\ 3 & \text { otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Exercises 2. Any function $s$ that satisfies the condition below is not computable. Note that there is no requirement of $s(n)$ when $n$ is not a square number.
$$\text{For all }n\in\mathbb N,\ s(n^2)=\begin{cases}2f_n(n^2) & \text { if both } f_{n}\text{ and }f_n(n^2) \text { are defined,} \\3n + 14043571  & \text { otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Dear John, Thank you very much for this very well explained answer! I now understand almost every detail about it, but would still like to ask a few questions about it. 1) Why do we talk here about diagonalization? I still didn’t quite get that? 2) Could we also have used another definition of f_n, or is the only possible definition of it? 3) “ However, whatever value we let (2022) be, there is a Turing machine that outputs
(2022) given 2022” and so on, can we easily prove this statement?

Comment: And I think something went wrong with the rendering of the text concerning the second exercise?

Comment: Please come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135245/chat-with-john-l) to chat with me.

Comment: thank you very much! :)

Comment: Little question: what is actually meant by f_n(n) is undefined? So if the turing machine corresponding with the encode number n gets the input n, we do not know what the output will be? And if f_n is undefined then that means that the turing machine simply doesn’t exist?

Comment: $f_n$ is undefined means that $n$ is not the encoding number of any Turing machine. When $f_n$ is defined, i.e., when $n$ is the encoding number of a Turing machine, $f_n$ is that Turing machine.  We say $f_n(n)$ is undefined to mean that $f_n$ does not halt when the input is $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!